# Show that if a Bipartite Graph's minimum degree is equal to n, then the Bipartite Graph's matching consists of at least n edges

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

It is absolutely intuitive that it has to be the case, but besides drawing (an example) a Bipartite Graph for |X|=3 and |Y|=3 and showing that for |X|=3 and |Y|=3, |X|=3 and |Y|=4 and |X|=4 and |Y|=4 with the minimal degree always being equal to 3 that its matching will always consist of at least 3 edges (and then generalising it for n instead of 3), I don't have an idea for a more "formal proof".

Such a "proof by example" is simply not satisfying to me

Comment: This is only a note of interest, since there're simpler proofs for your problem: If $G$ is *any* graph of order $n$ satisfying $\delta(G) \geq k$ and $n \geq 2k$, then $\alpha'(G) \geq k$. This is strictly stronger than your result, and the proof is relatively simple if you know the Berge-Tutte formula (a short corollary of Tutte's well-known $1$-factor theorem).

Comment: What's ′() ? And what's the Berge-Tutte formula (we haven't had this yet)?

Comment: $\alpha'(G)$ is the matching number of a graph $G$, i.e. the number of edges in a maximum matching in $G$. Berge-Tutte's formula states that in a graph of order $n$, $\alpha'(G) = \frac{1}{2}min_{S \subseteq V(G)}[n - (o(G - S) - \lvert S \rvert)]$, where $o(G- S)$ is the number of odd components in $G - S$. For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just take one vertex from X and assign it to one of its neighbors in Y. Now take another vertex from X and worst case scenario it will have n-1 neighbors that are not yet taken. Repeat the process and in the end you will take the nth vertex from X, which will have at least 1 neighbor that was not taken. You are done here.

Comment: "Now take another vertex from X and worst case scenario it will have n-1 neighbors that are not yet taken." - Why?

Comment: So you mean, that because the minimum degree here is n, then if I take another vertex from X then this vertex can have n-1 neighbors not taken in the worst case scenario (if the vertex from Y taken in the former step was a neighbor of this vertex in X), so you evaluate the worst case scenario which will get me n edges in the graph's matching, and in all those other scenarios there can be thus more than n edges in the graph's matching?

Comment: In my "worst case scenario" I assume that all the vertices I take are connected with the same n vertices from Y. If this is not the case, we just have more new vertices to choose from.